# JQuery variable does not exist in the current context

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to call another JQuery fuction from this one and the alert is able to use the variables `reviewMessage` and `payItemIDValue` but I receive an error on the refreshView line of code:

> The name 'payItemIDValue' does not exist in the current context

Why won't it recognize the variable name?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submitReview').click(function () {
            var reviewMessage = $('#message-text').val();
            var payItemIDValue = $('#payItemID').val();
            alert('PayItemID = ' + payItemIDValue + 'Message: ' + reviewMessage);
            refreshView('@Url.Action("RequestPayItemReview", "Employee", new { payItemID = payItemIDValue, message = "" })', '#employeeEditTabPanel')
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is `@Url.Action`? Are you using some templating language? Maybe razor? Can you add the corresponding tag? Anyway, that templating code executes *before* any of the JavaScript is executed, so you cannot mix-in JavaScript variables in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Razor. `@Url.Action` is server-side code, which is executed *before* any of the JavaScript code is executed. So you cannot reference JS variables in that `@Url.Action()` call. You'll have to append the JS value to it:

```
refreshView(`@Url.Action("RequestPayItemReview", "Employee")?payItemID='${payItemIDValue}&message=`, '#employeeEditTabPanel')
```